SVG filter fit image into rect
I tried the codes below to fit the feImage image to the rectangle, but the entire image does not fit. I specified the width and height in the viewBox value so that the image size is 500x200.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 200" fill="none">
            <defs>
                <filter id="filter">
                    <feImage width="100%" href="https://i.postimg.cc/C5nnQBRN/newYears.gif"/>
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="9px"/>
        </svg>
        <script>
            let rectElement = document.querySelector("rect");
            setTimeout(function() {
                rectElement.setAttribute("filter", "url(#filter)");
                rectElement.removeAttribute("stroke");
            }, 5000);
            
            
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert("Original image link");
            }, 8000);
            
            
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "https://i.postimg.cc/C5nnQBRN/newYears.gif";
            }, 10000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


pure SVG documents doesn't interpret HTML css @media commands...

Seems to work quite fine here, https://jsfiddle.net/pjwmbo3d/ Are you asking about a situation where you don't have the SVG code as part of the HTML, but have it embedded via img?

you can't use CSS media queries without HTML direct context

Please explain it does not work in the SVG document, doesn't mean anything, you mean in Adobe illustrator ?

@MisterJojo Can't run SVG document in Browser

@SYSCYCLE You will have to be a bit more helpful here: how are you testing this, where are you testing this? By default SVG documents indeed don't really do much with most CSS, as the browser is used to interpret them. "Can't run SVG document in Browser" - do you mean opening it with the browser? If it's a direct SVG element, the media query will be based on the size of the SVG document, not necessarily the viewport? We need more info.

Pleas explain Can't run SVG document in Browser. that's wrong. Actualy your SVG +  css code is plenty functional in the SO snippet here. and it work's on any browser.
